# How to implement a 'load more' functionality in react with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is the current flow of displaying a listing in our page:

I am calling an action reducer (`getListing()`) to get a listing of items via `mapDispatchToProps`

```
class Listing extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pageSize: 10
        };

        this.props.getlisting(10);
    }
```

The parameter '10' is just determining how many items to show. So this returns a listing of 10 items which I then render in the Listing's `render()` method:

```
listings.map(listing => {
    return (
        <ListingCard
            key={listing.id}
            listing={listing}
        />
    );
})}
```

Quite straightforward until this point. However at the end of the list, I need to have a load more button to load the next 10 items of the list. I imagine the method to be:

```
handleLoadMore() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({    
        pageSize: prevState.pageSize + 10
    }));
    this.props.getListing(this.state.pageSize);
}
```

With the intention of now getting a listing of 20 instead of just 10. And so on and so forth (e.g. 30, 40, increments of 10).

However, this doesn't work because the entire listing will re-render upon triggering the `handleLoadMore()`. The usual `'load more'` behavior keeps the initial result UI on the screen and just sort of appends the next X number of results.

How do I achieve this effect without re-rendering the entire list? Should I have a local state copy of the listings returned from the store?

Comment: Is ListingCard a functional component or a React.Component? If it is a React.Component you can compare the old props and the new props then decide to re-render or not. otherwise it will re-render every-time.

Comment: @Tan ListingCard is a react class component.

Comment: Cool then try to use React.PureComponent instead of React.Component. If this doesn't help check this Url to get more info about shouldcomponentupdate https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set anything in the local state. Simply make a call to `this.props.getListing`.

In your redux reducer/thunk/saga action, when it dispatches successfully, instead of replacing `this.props.listings`, add to it:

```
const initialState = {
  pageSize: 0,
  listings: []
}
​
function myApp(state, action) {
  if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
    return initialState
  }

  switch (action.type) {
     case FETCH_LISTINGS_SUCCESS:
          return {
            ..state,
            pageSize: state.pageSize + 10,
            listings: [...listings, ...action.listings]
          });
        default:
          return state
     }
}
```

Comment: I also realise the reason of the 'reloading ui' is my loading component condition.